# Download de arquivo a partir de preenchimento de um form

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, webforms, download, web-scraping

Estou tentando acessar um site, preencher seu formulário e fazer o download do arquivo, mas estou encontrando algumas dificuldades.

Esse é meu código até agora:

```
#library's
require(rvest)

#website
url <- ("http://www.anbima.com.br/est_termo/Curva_Zero.asp")
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgform <-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
param <- set_values(pgform, 
        "escolha" = "2",
        "Dt_Ref" = Sys.Date()
)

submit <- submit_form(pgsession, form = param, "Consultar")
```

Mas ele retorna um erro ao enviar o submit: `Erro: Could not find possible submission target.`

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O problema no submit, eh que o formulário não contém um botão "submit", aqui eu resolvi o problema criando um "fake submit" no formulario, mas testei aqui e apesar da requisição ter funcionado, não fez o download do arquivo... Provavelmente precisa de algum outro step para fazer o download

Comment: Coloquei o código com o submit funcionando em um gist, mas como falei, estou tendo apenas o retorno do submit e não um arquivo para donwload. Mas o erro que está dando na pergunta, não ocorre mais se você fizer isso... Se isso ajudar e resolver seu problema, eu faço um post tranformando esse comentário em resposta... https://gist.github.com/ibombonato/11507d776d1042f80ca59cd31509afd3

Comment: Mas você tem alguma ideia de como puxar esse download? Se fosse em um site com o botão submit, o que vc faria? Eu estou procurando aqui algo

Comment: Olhando o código fonte, tem um javscript e eu vi que o formulário precisa ser alterado e conter a url apontar para `CZ-down.asp` ao invés de `Curva_zero.asp`após isso, me parece que o arquivo é retornado no "response" da requisição em formato raw, mas eu não sei exatamente como converter isso para excel :-\ teria que dar uma pesquisada para descobrir se é possível fazer isso... Imagino que seja necessário criar uma conexão, ler o arquivo através dela e ai salvar o mesmo.

Comment: Substitui o .Curva_zero.asp pelo CZ-down.asp e usando a função download.file() deu certo. Era mto mais simples do que eu imaginava, mas é isso, valeu amigo!

Comment: Se possível, posta como ficou o código completo como resposta, assim outros podem ver  a solução inteira que você utilizou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como discutido com o amigo acima, era muito mais fácil do que o imaginado o resultado:

```
download.file("http://www.anbima.com.br/est_termo/CZ-down.asp", 
destfile = "")
```